# Complex result sets based on a pattern in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, zend-db-table

I have a table that has records attached to owners ids.

when I retrieve a result-set it is likely to have multiple rows belonging to the same owner.

I would like to order my results in a fair fashion to the owners showing 1 record for each owner and then repeating that process for their next records.

I have tried using order by FIELD('owner',{list,of,owners}) but this still groups all the records together showing all of one owners results before others.

Example:

```
Record | Owner | value
1      | A     | xyz
2      | A     | xyz
3      | B     | xyz
4      | C     | xyz
5      | C     | xyz
6      | B     | xyz
```

I would like this result set to be in the order of

```
Record | Owner
1      | A
3      | B
4      | C
2      | A
6      | B
5      | C
```

I am using Zend_Db_Table for my queries and cannot change. Therefore PHP / Mysqli based code please.

The order changes but is always in a pattern. I have access to the complete pattern at anytime telling me the order of the ids of the owners.

Can I achieve this without resorting to resorting the result set in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will work..

1. Create new column called `rank` to assign a rank for each row. The value of this column will be the rank grouped by owner.
2. Select columns needed from the output table of step 1 and order it by rank.

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/60606/28)

```
SELECT report,owner FROM (
        SELECT report,owner,value, IF(@prev <> owner, @cnt := 1, @cnt := @cnt + 1) AS rank, @prev := owner
        FROM x, (SELECT @prev := null, @cnt := 0) vars  
        ORDER BY owner
    ) as y ORDER BY y.rank,y.owner;
```

*NOTE: replace `x` with table name*

Comment: Thank you, Ill give this a go. Would it matter that I have 1000s of records?